# When I use HMSET to update mutil-data at same time. If some data update success,some data update failed?

Tags: redis

Just like:

```
hmset test_key test_filed1 first test_filed2 second
```

Will test_filed1 update success and test_filed2 update failed?

Answer (score 0):

`HMSET` is atomic, so it can only succeed or fail as a whole. Either both fields will be set successfully, or none and an error will be returned.

Note: `HMSET` is being deprecated and replaced by the more generic `HSET`.